# React Native v0.68 - A problem occurred configuring project ':react-native-async-storage_async-storage'

Tags: android, react-native, gradle, asyncstorage

I had tried everything mentioned in same error question asked earlier but it didn't worked for me.
Please help what is the problem here ?

Thankyou

$ react-native run-android
info Running jetifier to migrate libraries to AndroidX. You can disable it using "--no-jetifier" flagdid.
Jetifier found 1058 file(s) to forward-jetify. Using 4 workers...
info JS server already running.
info Installing the app...

> Configure project :app
> Unable to detect AGP versions for included builds. All projects in the build should use the same AGP version. Class name for the included build object: org.gradle.composite.internal.DefaultIncludedBuild$IncludedBuildImpl_Decorated.

Deprecated Gradle features were used in this build, making it incompatible with Gradle 8.0.

You can use '--warning-mode all' to show the individual deprecation warnings and determine if they come from your own scripts or plugins.

See https://docs.gradle.org/7.3.3/userguide/command_line_interface.html#sec:command_line_warnings
6 actionable tasks: 6 up-to-date

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

- What went wrong:
  A problem occurred configuring project ':react-native-async-storage_async-storage'.

> Could not load compiled classes for build file 'D:\aditya\pplwork\1-aditya-training\react-native\rn-igclone\node_modules@react-native-async-storage\async-storage\android\build.gradle' from cache.

- Try:

> Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace.
> Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output.
> Run with --scan to get full insights.

- Get more help at https://help.gradle.org

BUILD FAILED in 26s

error Failed to install the app. Make sure you have the Android development environment set up: https://reactnative.dev/docs/environment-setup.
Error: Command failed: gradlew.bat app:installDebug -PreactNativeDevServerPort=8081

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

- What went wrong:
  A problem occurred configuring project ':react-native-async-storage_async-storage'.

> Could not load compiled classes for build file 'D:\aditya\pplwork\1-aditya-training\react-native\rn-igclone\node_modules@react-native-async-storage\async-storage\android\build.gradle' from cache.

- Try:

> Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace.
> Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output.
> Run with --scan to get full insights.

- Get more help at https://help.gradle.org

BUILD FAILED in 26s

```
at makeError (D:\aditya\pplwork\1-aditya-training\react-native\rn-igclone\node_modules\execa\index.js:174:9)
at D:\aditya\pplwork\1-aditya-training\react-native\rn-igclone\node_modules\execa\index.js:278:16     
at processTicksAndRejections (node:internal/process/task_queues:96:5)
at async runOnAllDevices (D:\aditya\pplwork\1-aditya-training\react-native\rn-igclone\node_modules\@react-native-community\cli-platform-android\build\commands\runAndroid\runOnAllDevices.js:109:5)
at async Command.handleAction (D:\aditya\pplwork\1-aditya-training\react-native\rn-igclone\node_modules\@react-native-community\cli\build\index.js:192:9)
```

info Run CLI with --verbose flag for more details.
error Command failed with exit code 1.
info Visit https://yarnpkg.com/en/docs/cli/run for documentation about this command.

Comment: Hello. Can you do version control in android studio? gradle versions may have differed.

Comment: @cans yes changing gradle version build the bundle successfully. Thanks